# BibLaTeX - replace recurrent author by short name or Idem/Eadem in citations

Tags: biblatex

I am currently defining a (french) citation style. One thing I haven't managed to do is to replace the name of a recurring author by the short form in the citations. What I would like to do is :

> - Jane Smith, first work, Paris, 1900. [first citation from this author].
> - J. Smith, other work, Paris, 1901 [if not directly following the previous one].

or :

> - Ead., other work, Paris, 1901 [if directly following].

Is there a way of doing this? I have tried to use `\ifentryseen{author}` but without any success so far.

[edit] Here is how I try to do it (but I get an `! extra \else` error):

```
\newbibmacro*{author-fullnote}{%  
  \ifthenelse{\ifuseauthor\AND\NOT\ifnameundef{author}}%
    {\ifthenelse{\iffieldequals{namehash}{\bbx@lasthash}\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\bibstring[\mkidem]{idem\thefield{gender}}}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifentryseen{author}}{\printnames{labelname}}{
       \printnames[upshape][1-10]{author}
        \savefield{namehash}{\bbx@lasthash}}}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
```

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste: Did you enable the `idemtracker`? It would be good to have a minimal example for this.

Comment: @domwass
I have declared `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{idemtracker}` in the beginning of the bbx file. As for my example, I'll include it in my post, since it is too long for a comment.

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste: If you use 4-space indentation for a code block (which is good!), then you don't need backticks `\``.

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt, Duly noted !

Comment: I've noticed that, if I don't use `{\ifthenelse{\ifentryseen{author}}` but only `\ifentryseen{author}`, I no longer get the `! extra \else` error message, but, instead of "Ead.,", I get "Ead., J. Smith, Jane Smith"...

Comment: @domwass: I've seen that there is an option firstfullname in biblatex-dw, which is similar to what I want to do, but it doesn't work, by me, for two different works from the same author.

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste Camps: Again, it would be helpful to have a complete minimal example, since it is too time consuming too build one on my own. This applies both to your original question and to the question regarding biblatex-dw.

Comment: @domwass: I finally have succeeded. I was looking in footnote-dw instead of authortitle-dw. I adapted your code, I hope you don't mind ?
Should I post the solution here ?

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste Camps: You can of course use my code, it’s free (in the sense of the [LPPL](http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/)). I would recommend that you post your solution as an answer to your question – after all you have answered your own question, and others could benefit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here how I finally managed to do it, using code from the `Biblatex-dw` styles.
I added in the `cbx` :

```
% Option 'nameseen'
\newcommand*{\cbx@seennames}{}
\newrobustcmd*{\cbx@nameseen}[1]{%
\listxadd{\cbx@seennames}{\detokenize{#1}}}
\newrobustcmd*{\cbx@ifnameseen}[1]{%
\xifinlist{\detokenize{#1}}{\cbx@seennames}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
\DeclareNameFormat{citeauthor}{%
    \cbx@ifnameseen{#1#3#5#7}
        {\usebibmacro{name:first-last-upshape}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}%
        }%
        {\usebibmacro{name:first-last-upshape}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
        \cbx@nameseen{#1#3#5#7}}%
   \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
}
```

Where `first-last-upshape` is the format to be used in notes, with full first name the first time, and only initials the others. I then, in the `bbx`, defined two macros, inspired from the `historische-zeitschrift` style, to be applied in the full note (et al. only after ten names) and short notes (et al. after three names), each time specifying that idem/eadem/etc. should be used for the same author in two following references :

```
\newbibmacro*{author-fullnote}{%
    \ifthenelse{\ifuseauthor\AND\NOT\ifnameundef{author}}%
        {\ifthenelse
            {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
            {\bibstring{idem\thefield{gender}},}%
            {\printnames[citeauthor][1-10]{author}%        
        \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    }}%
    {\global\undef\cbx@lasthash}}

\newbibmacro*{author-shortnote}{%
    \ifthenelse{\ifuseauthor\AND\NOT\ifnameundef{author}}%
        {\ifthenelse
            {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
            {\bibstring{idem\thefield{gender}},}%
            {\printnames[citeauthor][1-3]{author}%        
        \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    }}%
    {\global\undef\cbx@lasthash}}
```

Here is what it looks like :

In following references :

[image: In following references]

In a further reference :

[image: In a further reference]