# Biblatex style short name

Tags: biblatex

I'm looking for a biblatex style which will create bibliography style according to scheme:

The first letter of the name, surname, title of the book, place of publication, year of publication.

I found only: [BibLaTeX - replace recurrent author by short name or Idem/Eadem in citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14795/biblatex-replace-recurrent-author-by-short-name-or-idem-eadem-in-citations)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve the result by the following modifications:

1. Use the option `firstinits=true`: Use only the first letter of the forname
2. Declare the format of the names to the order `first-last`. The order is specified in the name list format `sortname`. To change this, you can use:

   ```
   \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}
   ```

The complete MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authortitle,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Text \cite{companion}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]