# How to have the Bibliography style that is similar to chem-angew?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, overleaf

How can I get this Bibliography style https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110315/235725 with a number included on the left as `[1]` and the same for the cite part on the document?

From the Overleaf link https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Biblatex_bibliography_styles the most similar that I found was the `chem-angew` and the "More styles can be found in the [CTAN biblatex site](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex-contrib)" link is broken.

```
\documentclass{article}

 \usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew,sorting=nty]{biblatex}
 \addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} \begin{document} Text
 \cite{companion} 
 \printbibliography \end{document}
```

[image]

Could someone please help?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What is missing  in the chem-angew style?

Comment: @Bernard The year and the vol?. The year shouldn't be in bolds and the vol. shouldn't be in the middle of the year and the pages. It's vol., year, pages.

Comment: Could you please post a complete code, that we can compile as is, in order to test what can be done?

Comment: @Bernard .Done.

Comment: Is the vol. 322? or what's that number?

Comment: Probably – or the number of the  journal. This reference is not in `biblatex-example.bib`. For the year in bold face,  just add in your preamble `\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{#1}` (afrter loading biblatex).

Comment: @Bernard ? The bold doesn't show anymore but requires to load biblatex without the parevious parameters as I had `\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew,sorting=nty]{biblatex}`.

Comment: Not when I tested, provided biblatex is loaded before (so the field format declaration overwrites the field format declaration in the chem-angew style.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119997/discussion-between-vino-and-bernard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style from [Biblatex style short name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109281/35864) is just the `biblatex` standard style `authortitle` with two small adjustments: Name initials with `giveninits` (which was called `firstinits` a while ago) and different name order with `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family}` (`\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}` in old `biblatex` versions).

If you switch to the standard `numeric` style, the name format will already be as desired, so we only need to make the given names to come out as initials with `giveninits=true,`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, giveninits]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: E. Sigfridsson and U. Ryde. ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

---

As [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard) points out [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/584279/how-to-have-the-bibliography-style-that-is-similar-to-chem-angew#comment1468755_584279), you can use `\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{#1}` if you want to stick with `chem-angew` but want to get rid of the bold years.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=chem-angew]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{#1}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: E. Sigfridsson, U. Ryde, Journal of Computational Chemistry 1998, 19, 377–395.]